# UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle email_verified AttributeMapping missing in CDK construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

When adding **Google as IDP in Cognito** via Console in `Mapping attribute` there is an option to add `email_verified` attribute that will set email as **`Verified`** in your Cognito UserPool when you sign in.

But this attribute is missing in [`UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito.UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle.html) CDK construct.

The question is - does anyone know how to create custom attribute that will be possible to map as we are able to do via Console?

As you can see in the [AttributeMapping list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito.ProviderAttribute.html) this option does not exist.

Comment: Use `custom` in `AttributeMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_cognito as cognito

attribute_mapping = cognito.AttributeMapping(
    email=cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_EMAIL,
    family_name=cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_FAMILY_NAME,
    given_name=cognito.ProviderAttribute.GOOGLE_GIVEN_NAME,
    custom={
        "email_verified": cognito.ProviderAttribute.other("email_verified")
    }
)

user_pool = cognito.UserPool(self, "UserPool", ...)

cognito_user_pool_google_identity_provider = cognito.UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle(
    self,
    "CognitoUserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle",
    client_id="google_client_id",
    client_secret_value=self.google_cognito_secret.secret_value_from_json("google_client_secret"),
    scopes=["profile", "email", "openid"],
    user_pool=user_pool,
    attribute_mapping=attribute_mapping,
)
```